# Area51 does not show reputation changes

Tags: bug, reputation, area-51, reputation-graph

When I open the [reputation page on my Area51 profile](http://area51.stackexchange.com/users/46349/juergen-d?tab=reputation) I see no reputation entries.

[image: reputation changes]

Why is that? I have 168 reputation.

Comment: I'd imagine this has something to do with deleted "posts" on proposals that no longer exist. I don't think Area 51 got the change for showing removed posts in the history. Also, it doesn't appear that referrals and fulfilled commitment bonuses are showing up.