# 101 - 6 + 10 = 97

Tags: bug, reputation, area-51, reputation-recalc

I may missed something, but it looks like there's [a problem](http://area51.stackexchange.com/users/106375?tab=reputation) :[image: screenshot of my reputation tab on Area51]

Comment: Not 100% sure if it's a duplicate or not: [Area51 does not show reputation changes](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/196857/187824). Only different is your profile shows *some* reputation changes.

Comment: @hims056 : No, all reputation changes are listed here. It seems there's a problem on the total reputation count.

Comment: Go to http://area51.stackexchange.com/reputation and calculate the actual rep changes. (Trigger the reputation recalc)

Comment: @hims056 : Ok I didn't know about reputation-recalc. I recognize I used the tag without understanding what it mean. Can you write an answer describing where do you found the link with a screenshot?

Comment: Ohh hell.. I just triggered it and my rep is decreased from [345](http://i.stack.imgur.com/QcsyK.png) to 272. WTF??

Comment: @user2284570 You can click on any tag to find out more about it. Most of them have at least a short description of what the tag's about at the top of the tag page, and some have a fuller explanation after you click "read more".

Comment: @Yannis : Yes I did, but I didn't understood the description.

Comment: @hims056 LOL!!! Punishment for trying to be good. ;)

Comment: @user2284570 there's no official link to this page, it's known to the long time members here and these days  recalc is possible only in Area 51, it's disabled on all other sites.

Comment: @ShadowWizard : Why it has been disabled on Stackoverflow? Looks like there [have been an hyperlink](http://meta.stackexchange.com/tags/reputation-recalc/info) in the past. So the tag wiki should be edited.

Comment: @user2284570 due to rep eating worm. Seriously now, there was a nasty bug causing reputation to suddenly drop for random users but when recalced, the reputation got back to normal. So to track the bug down they disabled the option to recalc... and never put it back.

Comment: The original bug report for the above is http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/213000/what-happened-to-this-users-rep-badges-and-name

Comment: @ShadowWizard Do you have a link to the post on Meta which explain the disable status of reputation-recalc?  I also don't understand why it is still enabled on Area51.

Comment: @user2284570 no official post about it, was mentioned in chat or comments though by Nick. As for Area 51 it's working on a different code base so they didn't touch it.

Comment: @ShadowWizard : Sorry for insisting, but can you give some links to such comments?

Comment: @nicael because OP here triggered reputation recalc.

Comment: @user2284570 sorry, couldn't find it at the moment. But believe me, I'm not making this up. :)

Comment: OK, found some reference from Shog (highest ranking CM) in comments on a [deleted post](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/213003/152859): http://i.stack.imgur.com/kpZJe.png

Comment: I can't figure it out.  My eyes can't pass "Does IPv5 ever existed?" without rolling up into the back of my head :/

Comment: @ShadowWizard : What??? a giraffe with animals on it? you must be a funny guy! Anyway I found the post [myself](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/43005/242800)

Comment: @Won't : That's why I included a screenshot in my question.

Comment: @user2284570 if you check the revisions you'll see it was my edit in there. I thought you were looking for a more "official" statement?

Comment: [Looks correct-ish](http://i.stack.imgur.com/mW2db.png) now, but you should generally not expect the Reputation tab on Area 51 to show all of the changes. I forget exactly how it works (or doesn't work), but some show up, some don't.

Comment: @Anna the problem was and still is major gaps between the actual reputation and displayed reputation, which is "fixed" by manually recalculating it. See [this](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/231222/100-6-10-97#comment759736_231222) for example - but guess no point trying to fix this, right?

Comment: @ShadowWizard It's ... How do I put this. Area 51 is a very old fork of the original SE codebase. There be dragons in there (probably literally). I don't know exactly where the challenges for fixing this would be, but in any event, we're not putting any significant time into A51 dev at this point.

Comment: Totally fair, @Anna - thanks! :)

Comment: @Anna Hey, a couple years ago Robert C had mentioned there's an Area 51 3.0 in the works.  Was that abandoned or still progressing slowly?

Comment: @Troyen Not really sure what the status of that is at this point.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Area 51 reputation might not be updated by itself so in those cases when you suspect your reputation is incorrect you can manually recalculate it from within the [reputation audit page](http://area51.stackexchange.com/reputation):

> [image]

This will "fix" the display and might result in decreasing the reputation, so don't blame me! :)

Comment: I'm not recalculating. I want to keep that Spam Review rep, thanks.